# dynamiccally set up update statement not working

Tags: php

its shows that syntax error in sql statement with this message 
database query failed : ... use right syntax near " at line 1
however i can't find one plz help

```
public function update(){
    global $database;
    $attributes = $this->attributes();
    $attribute_pairs = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        # code...
        $attribute_pairs[] = "$key = $value";
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
    $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
    $sql .= " WHERE id=".$this->id;
    $database->query($sql);
    return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: ` $attribute_pairs[] = "$key = $value";` this should be  `$attribute_pairs[] = $value;`

Comment: try echoing $sql and use it in db

Comment: i want to get each value of$attribute_pairs as of the form "username = 'nischal'", "password = 'nischal12345'"... then join them so that the statement has something like this "username='nischal', password = 'nischal'..."

Comment: So `$attribute_pairs[] = "$key = $value";` should be `$attribute_pairs[] = "$key = '$value'";` instead.